# Make a list of words from text file and search these words by letters from input

Tags: python, list

Ok, I'm a newbie so I appreciate any clues and hints. This is my first question here, so sorry about anything messy! I have found a lot of help with other types of lists and magic tricks, and some things, but not much, that I can use in this one.

I want to make a list from my little text file (containing all the words in the universe). First I want the user to write some letters, then I want to list words which contain these letters. The letters being "abcdeir" for example, the list would go "bad", "bar", "beard", etc.

Here is what I have so far:

```
file = open("allthewords.txt", "r")
```

Comment: So, (if I got it right), you want the user to input some letters, then to open a file, and to list every word containing instances of any of those letters? Are you matching single letters only, or do you wish to match for example "ver" (in riVER) as well? Cause the letter "a" and "e" will pretty much match all words...

Comment: oh i missed out, of course it will. i need it to write ONLY words with <= 9 and > 4 letters,   and the fifth letter (str[4]?) need to be in all the words.   

letters = raw_input("Letters: ")

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sets for this:

```
letters = set("abcdeir")
with open("allthewords.txt", "r") as f:
  for word in f:
    if set(word) <= letters: # check that all letters of `word` are in `letters`
      print word
```

You can tweak this as required.

Comment: I'd use `set`s, too. You may need to use `set(word.strip())`, though.

Comment: hooray! figured out the .strip() thing all by my self :)  it looks great. now i need to exclude all the words with <4 or >9 letters from the list. don't be shy!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write it out in pseudocode, and then execute it:

```
letters = "abcdeir" # Alternatively,  letters = raw_input('Input letters: ')
with open("allthewords.txt", "r") as file:
  for word in file:
    if all(character in letters for character in word):
      print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp if in your file some words would be in a same line.

```
import re
with open('your_file.txt','r') as f: 
    print re.findall(r"\b[abcdeir]+\b", f.read())
```